# How do I run multiple Selenium tests from Jenkins simultaneously?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, testng

Current setup:
Jenkins points to -> POM.xml [3 Profiles setup - each pointing to a different env] -> Profile 1 points to ->testng1.xml, Profile 2 points to ->testng2.xml, Profile 3 points to ->testng3.xml.

I hope that makes sense so far.

**I would like to know how I can fire off two or more jobs at the same time with out getting this error in the console:**

```
Executing Maven:  -B -f C:/Users/user1/workspace/project1/pom.xml clean test site org.reportyng:reporty-ng:1.2:reportyng -Pbenen1

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) on project project1: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete
```

**Would using the XVFB plugin allow me to run multiple tests simultaneously on the same machine?**

I have a feeling this is related to the fact that all of these TestNG.xml files live in the same project and therefore share the same target, src, and test-output folders. I'm not sure how to separate those out per testng.xml test suite.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: TestNG is your test manager in this setup. Try the documentation for TestNG.

Answer (score 0):

We have been running concurrently successfully.  We do not have profiles defined but we run with different parameters as below.

1. Have checked the Execute concurrent builds if necessary in the Jenkins configuration.
2. Build step is `clean generate-sources test -DsuiteXmlFile=src/test/resources/GroupBased_Tests.xml`
3. And each build runs with different values of parameters.

You can try to parameterize the suite xml instead of making it through profiles.

HTH.

Comment: I don't understand steps 2 and 3.  Is this a maven parameter:

`-DsuiteXmlFile=src/test/resources/GroupBased_Tests.xml`

Where do you pass the environment parameters when your run it from Jenkins?

I'm using parameters within my testng.xml files.  I have three different testng.xml files with three different environment parameters setup. 

I'm not sure if I'm doing it right or wrong but it seems to be working, except for the whole running concurrently part.

Comment: It's a maven surefire plugin option to run Testng tests.  Surefire plugin is tied to the test phase.  Basically, the parallel runs in our case are left to Jenkins , which creates temp workspace for each of the concurrent builds.

Comment: If you use Jenkins to parametrize your build and take the XML as your parameter instead of creating 3 diff profiles, you can build 3 times. (not the Testng parameters, they can stay in ur XML)